# Grunt does not return anything

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I used to use the ground in my previous computer (that died), and now I try to use it in my new computer. The problem is that I get no response when I use it.

More specific, I have gone to the folder that the `Gruntfile` resists and I run the command `grunt watch`, but I don't get any response from the `Grunt`

My command line looks like that:

```
merianos@merianos-pc:~/Documents/repositories/project/wp-content/themes/cours-de-musique/bower_components/bootstrap$ grunt watch
merianos@merianos-pc:~/Documents/repositories/project/wp-content/themes/cours-de-musique/bower_components/bootstrap$
```

In addition, I have tried the command `npm list --depth=0 | grep grunt-contrib-compass` and I got the following results:

```
npm ERR! max depth reached: btoa@1.1.2, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt@0.4.5, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: glob@4.0.6, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-autoprefixer@1.0.1, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-banner@0.2.3, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-clean@0.6.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-concat@0.5.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-connect@0.9.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-copy@0.7.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-csslint@0.3.1, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.10.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-jade@0.13.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-jshint@0.10.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-less@0.12.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-qunit@0.5.2, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-uglify@0.6.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-csscomb@3.0.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-exec@0.4.6, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-html-validation@0.1.18, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-jekyll@0.4.2, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-jscs@0.8.1, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-saucelabs@8.3.3, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: grunt-sed@0.1.1, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: load-grunt-tasks@1.0.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: npm-shrinkwrap@5.1.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: time-grunt@1.0.0, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! max depth reached: remarkable@1.4.2, required by bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**Note:** The same file system used in the previous computer, and worked normally, but now in the new computer I have this problem. You should also know that I have not touched any of the files related to this project.

**UPDATE 1**

I have also tried `grunt --version` and again the result is the same:

```
merianos@merianos-pc:~/Documents/repositories/project/wp-content/themes/cours-de-musique/bower_components/bootstrap$ grunt --version
merianos@merianos-pc:~/Documents/repositories/project/wp-content/themes/cours-de-musique/bower_components/bootstrap$
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved:

The solution was following:

I opened the file `/usr/local/bin/grunt` and I replaced the following line

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```